# javascript callback function from different scope variable not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function coolo()
{
    var tile1 = -1;
    var tile2 = -1;
    $(".grid-cell").click(swap);
}


function swap()
{
    console.log(tile1)
}

coolo();
```

Of course I will get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: tile1 is not defined` error. I can fix it by passing the variable to the function or putting the variable in global scope. Is there a way for the `swap` function to access variables in the scope of `coolo`? I can access variables in global scope, so why not this? I've tried using the `this` keyword, but `jquery` assigns `this` to the dom element that has been selected. I'm not sure if using `this` would work in a non `jquery` situation either. If there isn't, I'd like to learn more about how scoping works in javascript.

Comment: `function swap(tile1)` ... `.click(swap.bind(null, tile1))`

Comment: You should look up some [OOP JavaScript patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/).

Comment: You should read about [lexical scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Lexical_scoping) in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes! I saw that link before but this is the one I was looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to pass an argument to that function, but you can make it little bit more generic

```
function coolo()
{
    var tile1 = -1;
    var tile2 = -1;
    $(".grid-cell").click(function(){swap(title1)});
}


function swap(title)
{
    console.log(tile)
}

coolo();
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to know about scope, this will work. As you only use `swap` inside `coolo`, there's no reason not to put `swap` inside the `coolo` function, thus in the same scope as tile1

```
function coolo() {
    var tile1 = -1;
    var tile2 = -1;
    var swap = function () {
        console.log(tile1)
    }
    $(".grid-cell").click(swap);
}

coolo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Define it as global variable  outside these two function or use window.title

```
var title 
function A(){

}
function B(){

}
```

or pass it as a parameter to the second function

```
function A(){
  B(title);
}
```